# Restarting the app with setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I want to restart my app with a button, but it's not working.
I have the following situation:
Activities: A, B, C, D, E, F
I navigate through the activities as follows: `A > B > A > C > A > D > E > F`

When I go from A to B, I use `startActivitie`, when I go from A to C, I use `startActivityForResult`.

Now I want to go back to activity A, restarting the app, but it is not working.

This is what I'm using on the activity F:

```
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

And that's what I'm using on activity A:

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        finish();
    }
```

The problem is, when I click the button I go back to activity B.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In onClickListener `onClick` method there is no need for `getApplicationContext()` just replace it with:

```
intent = new Intent(F.this, A.class);
```

The problem is this condition becomes `true`:

```
getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)
```

and call

```
finish();
```

Which means the activity should be destroyed so please if you want A to continue on button click go in activity **F** intent put extra as `false` in this line:

**Change**

```
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
```

**To**

```
intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
```

And A will appear without being finished. Because the condition `getIntent.getBooleanExtra("EXIT",false)` will be false now!

Comment: I didnt see the error now I have seen it. You put extra as `true` in activity **F**

Comment: Consider making my answer as accepted answer, since it works! @MateusNogueira

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

> This launch mode can also be used to good effect in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: if used to start the root activity of a task, it will bring any currently running instance of that task to the foreground, and then clear it to its root state.

So .. .try adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. You might also have to override `onNewIntent()` instead of relying solely on `onCreate()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That was not a problem according to his logic, Though it was totally unnecessary and can be omitted. I thought the same but I later on edited my answer! @dominicoder